# Show events in the middle of day in month-timline view in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, timeline

I would need to show events in month-timeline view in FullCalendar from the middle of the day, as you can see on the picture below.

Every event starts in the middle of the day and ends just like that. If another event starts the same day, is on the same line and it starts in the middle of day as well.

At the top of my head is to specify hours in "start" and "end" parameters of every event, but it is not used in month-timline view (in header, there are only days, not hours).

Is here a way to how to do it?

[image]

Comment: You can do it by a) customising the `slotDuration` setting so that it is more granular (e.g. 12-hour slots instead of 1-day slots) and b) specifying the hours in the start and end properties of the events, so fullCalendar knows more precisely where to put them on the grid. The reason it can't work as you want in the default version of the month view is quite simple and logical: the grid is only sensitive to whole days. If you want more accuracy then you have to change the grid layout to show more detail (which is done using slotDuration). Try that. If you get stuck, post your code.

Comment: Thank you, I set `slotDuration` to `12:00`, then `slotLabelInterval` to `24:00` and in CSS I reset dotted vertical line `.fc-time-area .fc-slats .fc-minor` and it looks exactly what I want to, perfect.

One more issue I have while dragging. I would need that snaping would be available also in "half-days" only. I tried set it via `snapDuration` to `24:00`, but nothing happend. And also resizing of event should be available only by 24h steps, just like snapping while dragging.

Comment: " I would need that snaping would be available also in "half-days" only"...if slotDuration is 12 hours, then you're already restricted only to 00:00 or 12:00 as start times. You can then further use the `eventAllow` callback to check the start time and block the drop operation at that point, if it's not at 12:00. Have a really good look through the documentation, because there's all sorts of callbacks and options which might help you do various things - it's a good idea to be aware of what tools are available to you for tasks such as this. You have a lot of control, potentially.

Answer (score 0):

set
**slotDuration** : '12:00' and
**slotLabelInterval**  : '24:00'